# node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/lib/mutation.js:153:10 in Mutation#execute react native expo

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, react-query

I'm buiding React Native Expo App with external rest api.

I have created reusable axios api call:

```
// axiosAPi.js
export const axiosApi = async (method, url, obj = {}) => {
    try {
      switch (method) {
        case 'GET':
          return await axios
            .get(`${baseUrl}/${url}`, config)
            .then((res) => res.data)
  
        case 'POST':
          return await axios
            .post(`${baseUrl}/${url}`, obj, config)
            .then((res) => res.data)
  
        case 'PUT':
          return await axios
            .put(`${baseUrl}/${url}`, obj, config)
            .then((res) => res.data)
  
        case 'DELETE':
          return await axios
            .delete(`${baseUrl}/${url}`, config)
            .then((res) => res.data)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error?.response?.data?.error
    }
  }
```

I have created a hook with login instance using react-query:

```
// api/index.js
  export default function useApiHook() {
    const login = useMutation((obj) => axiosApi('POST', `auth/login`, obj))
  
    return { login }
  }
```

Here is the implementation of login screen

```
// screens/login.js
const loginPostMutation = useApiHook()?.login

const submitHandler = (data) => {
    loginPostMutation
      ?.mutateAsync(data)
      ?.then((res) => res)
      .catch((err) => err)
}
```

When I send correct credentials is returns the data with no errors, but when I send incorrect credentials it returns the error + this warning in the console:

**Invalid credentials
at node_modules/@tanstack/query-core/build/lib/mutation.js:153:10 in Mutation#execute**

Answer (score 0):

The line in question points towards react-query logging the error to the console in development mode. `Invalid credentials` is thus just an error that is returned from `axios`, very likely, a 401 - Unauthorized error.

You would very likely get the same error when making the axios request without  react-query.

Comment: Invalid credentials are what I needed to return, without react-query I'm not having any issues logging in to the console. So how do I resolve that warning from react-query?